# How to (y) align divs above the bottom of previous line?

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to create a column layout by filling in fixed-width divs inside a width:100% container div, letting them "wrap" when there is no room left in the container, thus creating the columns. To change the # of columns, I just change the width of the contained divs. Those contained divs can be pretty tall..

Here is what I have now:

```
+------------------------------+
|+----+ +----+ +----+ +----+   |
||    | |    | |    | |    |   |
||    | |    | |    | |    |   |
||    | |    | |    | |    |   |
|+----+ +----+ +----+ |    |   |
|                     |    |   |
|                     |    |   |
|                     |    |   |
|                     +----+   |
|+----+ +----+ +----+ +----+   |
||    | |    | |    | |    |   |
||    | |    | |    | |    |   |
||    | |    | |    | |    |   |
|+----+ +----+ +----+ +----+   |
|                              |
```

See this big waisted space where the sized divs wrap and align on the bottom of the tallest div of the previous line? I guess that is how HTML's box-model works.

But in this very case, what I would like to obtain is this:

```
+------------------------------+
|+----+ +----+ +----+ +----+   |
||    | |    | |    | |    |   |
||    | |    | |    | |    |   |
||    | |    | |    | |    |   |
|+----+ +----+ +----+ |    |   |
|+----+ +----+ +----+ |    |   |
||    | |    | |    | |    |   |
||    | |    | |    | |    |   |
||    | |    | |    | +----+   |
|+----+ +----+ +----+ +----+   |
|                     |    |   |
|                     |    |   |
|                     |    |   |
|                     +----+   |
|                              |
```

Any idea?

Comment: Your right the box model is why your ending up with your current layout. To get around that you will have to use javascript most likely (not 100% sure on that but I don't see any other way around the box model)

Comment: Check out Isotope: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/introduction.html

Comment: Wow, Isotope is really intriguing. Why is your comment not an answer? Because from the looks of it both you and ryan are right: This is a mission for JS. thanks!

Comment: I think http://masonry.desandro.com/ may be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Check out something like this, it's almost identical to Pinterest...

http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin